# Event handler function ignores some functions

Tags: c#, winforms, powerpoint

I am using a globalhook classfrom code project to control powerpoint slideshow with custom keys (windows form application) I want the powerpoint object to close when anykey is pressed but the event handler ignores this function and refuses to make any actions unless it's in the scope of the main form. here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PowerPoint.Application objApp;
    PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet;
    PowerPoint._Presentation objPres;
    PowerPoint.Slides objSlides;
    PowerPoint._Slide objSlide;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserActivityHook actHook;
        objApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
        actHook = new UserActivityHook(); // crate an instance with global hooks

        // hang on events

        actHook.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MyKeyPress);
        objPresSet = objApp.Presentations;
        objPres = objPresSet.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        objSlides = objPres.Slides;
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    // UserActivityHook actHook;

    public void MyKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();

         button1.Hide(); //executes normally 
         Form2.Show(); //no action
         objApp.Quit(); // no action
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
    }   
}
```

Comment: i have successfully ran  Form2.Show(); objApp.Quit()   functions in debug mode and putting a break point at button1.Hide();then proceeding by F10 the following two functions execute successfully  but when i run it just execute button1.Hide() and ignores the other two. not even an error or exception. plz Help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HookManager class from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx?msg=2856887) it works fine with me.

Comment: i already use this class but version 1 because version 2 has some issues and it's demo project throws an exception.

Comment: it works but when the event handler has a function related to objapp powerpoint application object the function is ignored. thx